# Displaying a count when using an array

Tags: java, arrays, count

This is the problem for my homework. 
Write a program in a class NumberAboveAverage that counts the number of
days that the temperature is above average. Read ten temperatures from the
keyboard and place them in an array. Compute the average temperature
and then count and display the number of days on which the temperature
was above average.

I have the code written and everything outputs correctly except the day count. I can't figure out how to fix it. Any suggestions?

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
final int NUMBER_OF_TEMPERATURES = 10;
double[] temperature = new double[NUMBER_OF_TEMPERATURES];
int temperatureCount = 0;
double total = 0;

//Reads temperature & counts entries.
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a temperature:");
    temperature[i] = input.nextDouble();
    total = total + temperature[i];
    temperatureCount++;
}

//Computes the average 
double averageTemp = total/NUMBER_OF_TEMPERATURES;
System.out.println("The average temperature is " + averageTemp); 

//Displays temperatures above average. 
System.out.println("The temperatures above average are as follows: ");
for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++)
{
    if (temperature[i]> averageTemp)
        System.out.println("Day " + i + 1 + ":" + temperature[i]);
}

}
```

These are the results I get when I run it.

```
Enter a temperature:
98
Enter a temperature:
94
Enter a temperature:
93
Enter a temperature:
96
Enter a temperature:
91
Enter a temperature:
92
Enter a temperature:
90
Enter a temperature:
96
Enter a temperature:
99
Enter a temperature:
94
The average temperature is 94.3
The temperatures above average are as follows: 
Day 01:98.0
Day 31:96.0
Day 71:96.0
Day 81:99.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to group i and 1 in the output line (if I understand the question properly). Currently, it may output "Day 01", "Day 31" because you output i, then "1". Change your output line to:

```
System.out.println("Day " + (i + 1) + ":" + temperature[i]);
```

and that should fix it up. Currently, it is outputting 5 different sections:

1. "Day "
2. i
3. 1
4. ":"
5. temperature[i]

If my understanding is correct, you want to start your day count from 1 (rather than 0, which arrays start at). To do that, we increase the value of "i" by 1 in the output. By grouping the "i + 1" we force the output engine to add them together, rather than treat them as two separate outputs. Grouping gives us:

1. "Day "
2. (i + 1)
3. ":"
4. temperature[i]

Comment: Wow, really? As easy as that? Thanks a million, it worked! Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: No worries! It's often the easiest things we miss, and having someone else check it can locate them easily.

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing is that  if there is string before "+" operator in a any statement and you have to perform any arithmetic operations then always do them inside brackets.

like as "sum"+5+6 generate output "sum=56"
or if you  use it like that "sum="+(5+6) then o/p is "sum=11"

** use of + operator :-
1."String1"+"string2"(to concatenate two strings).
2. if there is statement without any string like we take you

```
your code:=  "System.out.println("Day " + i + 1 + ":" + temperature[i]);"

try it :=  "System.out.println(i + 1 + "Day " + ":" + temperature[i]);"
```

(it will work). Because there is no string before "i+1" in statement.

And please try to understand concepts behind  "+" in oops programming.